# Show duplicate action outlet

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, xib

I have been using Mac OS - El Capitan (Version 10.11.2) and Xcode - 7.2 and developing projects using xib.

In my project multiple button in performing the same action, so I have managed button tag base action manage, but my project in some button action outlet creates, in my xib’s header file show created an action method, but my xib file, right click to show the my UIController outlet list in “Received Action” section show duplicate the action and also same as Connections Inspector.

Following I have put snap shot for help understand my question.

[image]

[image]

So, why my button Action outler show duplicates?

If I have any mistake to create or set outlet action?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you declare a public function of the same name in .h file.

Comment: No my friend @Lumialxk, i have not create and declare custom function of this name

Answer (score 0):

My guess is, you have two methods with same name but with different parameters.

Answer (score -1):

Mostly multiple button in performing the same action, to create the button `Outlet collection`.

[image]

Developer occurred mistake of creating button action time connection sets property `Action`, and click to `Connect` button but not set an `Arguments` property and system take the default `Sender` property. This is a mistake to show double Outlet action.

[image]

Set the following property to not show double auction outlet.

[image]